# undefined symbol : qemu_plugin_get_thread_id()

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, qemu

I have added a new function in api.c file (qemu/plugins/api.c) : 
`int qemu_plugin_get_qemu_tid(void)` 
I made changes in qemu/plugins/qemu-plugins.symbols and qemu/include/qemu/qemu-plugin.h as well 
I am calling this function in qemu/contrib/plugins/howvec.c but it is showing error: 
`undefined symbol: qemu_plugin_get_qemu_tid`
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here and belong on [so].